# Laravel Blade template - cannot get to relation, but i know it's pulled from db and exists

Tags: php, laravel, object, view, laravel-blade

Without losing any time.

I have relations

```
class Product extends Model
{
     public function images() {
           return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Image', 'imageable')->limit(1);
     }
}
```

and image model

```
class Image extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['path', 'small', 'orginal', 'default'];

    // ATTRIBUTES
    public function getPathAttribute() {
        return "uploaded/{$this->id}/";
    }

    public function getOrginalAttribute() {
        return $this->path.'orginal.jpg';
    }

    public function getDefaultAttribute() {
        return $this->path.'default.jpg';
    }

    public function getSmallAttribute() {
        return $this->path.'small.jpg';
    }

    // RELATIONSHIPS
    public function imageable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

and in view i was trying to do

```
$advert->images->first()->path
```

but im getting error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

however if i `dd()` this line, it returns `uploaded/5/`
Previously i had `morphOne()` instead of `morphMany()`, but the only way it seems to work is to put it in `foreach` loop like that.

```
@foreach($advert->images as $image) 
        <img src="{{ asset($image->small) }}">
    @endforeach
```

now it works, but when i want to get into images without `foreach` loop it says the above error.

To avoid any questions about eager load, i did it.
Any help?

Comment: did you try `$advert->images->first()` and what is the return. the error show that you don't have any property from this object `$advert->images->first()`

Comment: thats the whole magic im trying to figure out. `first()` returns Image model object!!! but when i access it it says the above error. when i echo object it shows me `{"id":6,"user_id":1,"imageable_id":26,"imageable_type":"App\\Models\\Advert","created_at":"2016-06-08 03:31:10","updated_at":"2016-06-08 03:31:10","path":"uploaded\/6\/","small":"uploaded\/6\/small.jpg","orginal":"uploaded\/6\/orginal.jpg","default":"uploaded\/6\/default.jpg"}`. Now i tried to get to propery with array notation and it works, seems like only getting to it as a object breaks the script. Im using paginator btw.

Comment: so summarizing: this `$advert->images->first()` works, this `$adverts->first()->images->first()->small` before advert loop works as well , however inside the `adverts` loop only these work `$advert->images->first()['small']` and `@foreach($advert->images as $image) 
        <img src="{{ asset($image->small) }}">
    @endforeach` I think it might be wrong something with laravel, cant figure anything else out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Sorry for the mess.

Looked like the last `$advert` didn't have any images and i was trying to get into them, but they didn't exist, so the laravel thrown error that i was trying to access non-existing property.

so the whole fix for it was to add `if`

```
@if ($advert->images) 
        <img src="{{ asset($advert->images->small) }}">
    @endif
```

stupid mistake, but it took me more than hour.
hope it saves someone time.